# TypeError: 'data' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, python-requests, keyword-argument

I'm trying to modify the function `request` to take different arguments depending on the api call. For example: in `post_categories`, I need it to send a third parameter `data` that includes the body that I want to post, but the `get_categories` function doesn't need a third parameter.  I added `**kwargs` to the request function but this is the error that I'm getting: `TypeError: 'data' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

```
class ApiGateway():
    base_url = 'https://api.com/v3/'

    def request(self, method, endpoint, **kwargs):
        url = f'{self.base_url}{endpoint}'
        kwargs.setdefault('headers', {})
        kwargs['headers'].update({
            'Authorization': f'Bearer ${self.token}',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        })
        response = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
        return response.json()

    def get_categories(self, merchant_id):
        endpoint = f'merchants/{merchant_id}/categories'
        return self.request('GET', endpoint)

    def post_categories(self, merchant_id):
        update = {
            'payment_method': {
                'token': 1234,
                'data': '123556'
            }
        }    
        endpoint = f'merchants/{merchant_id}/categories'
        return self.request('POST', endpoint, data=json.dumps(update))
```

Comment: If you're sending a JSON object, shouldn't you be using the json keyword instead of data? [ref](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/)

Comment: Showing the traceback might help.  Just to make sure that the error is being produced where you/we think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution. i had to specify the type of data i wanted to pass to the `request` function  instead of passing the data as a kwargs parameter. i just updated  this part of the `post_categories` function `return self.request('POST', endpoint, data=json.dumps(update))` so now the function looks like this

```js
   def post_categories(self, merchant_id):
        update = {
            'payment_method': {
                'token': 1234,
                'data': '123556'
            }
        }    
        endpoint = f'merchants/{merchant_id}/categories'
   
        return self.request('POST', endpoint, json=update) # <-- updated third parameter
```